# Interpolate Columnar Data

Tags: linux, awk, csv, ascii

I am trying to find a way to interpolate between two lines of data in a CSV file, likely using `awk`. Right now, each line represents a data point at Hour 0 and Hour 6. I am looking to fill in missing hourly data between Hour 0 and Hour 6.

**Current CSV**

```
lat,lon,fhr
33.90000,-76.50000,0
34.20000,-77.00000,6
```

**Expected Interpolated Output**

```
lat,lon,fhr
33.90000,-76.50000,0
33.95000,-76.58333,1
34.00000,-76.66667,2
34.05000,-76.75000,3
34.10000,-76.83333,4
34.15000,-76.91667,5
34.20000,-77.00000,6
```

Comment: Does the file contain *only* two lines of data (plus header), or are you looking for a solution that operates on successive pairs of lines? or interpolates arbitrary data to a specific grid?

Comment: The full CSV file contains 32 more lines so, I figure if I can figure out a way to perform this interpolation on the first two lines, the same process can be replicated by going down the lines

Comment: Full CSV file: https://pastebin.com/jksdd3LG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this file:

```
cat file
```

```
lat,lon,fhr
33.90000,-76.50000,0
34.20000,-77.00000,6
34.20000,-77.50000,12
```

then

```
awk -F, '
    function interpolate(lat1, lon1, t1, lat2, lon2, t2,      i) {
        for (i = 1; i <= (t2 - t1); i++) {
            printf "%.5f,%.5f,%d\n",
                lat1 + i * (lat2 - lat1) / (t2 - t1),
                lon1 + i * (lon2 - lon1) / (t2 - t1),
                t1   + i
        }
    }
    NR <= 2 {print}
    NR >= 3 {interpolate(lat, lon, t, $1, $2, $3)}
    {lat = $1; lon = $2; t = $3}
' file
```

```
lat,lon,fhr
33.90000,-76.50000,0
33.95000,-76.58333,1
34.00000,-76.66667,2
34.05000,-76.75000,3
34.10000,-76.83333,4
34.15000,-76.91667,5
34.20000,-77.00000,6
34.20000,-77.08333,7
34.20000,-77.16667,8
34.20000,-77.25000,9
34.20000,-77.33333,10
34.20000,-77.41667,11
34.20000,-77.50000,12
```